# using angularjs directive for icheck plugin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, icheck

I've a problem with my Angularjs app, cannot figure out where is the problem.

check it on plunker [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZorJLzwVjk1akLknaPu?p=preview)

when I click the button it should run the iCheck() plugin, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do one thing in order to get everything working: **force AngularJS to actually use jQuery**.

AngularJS includes jQlite in its source code, but it's not the same as jQuery. If you include jQuery **before** angular.js then Angular will use it instead of own implementation.

Thus just change this in index.html:

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.9" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
```

(jQuery is before angular.js)

[working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9IkEb2UH6S1LfS5Zb0Qf?p=preview)

Answer (score 9):

A better iCheck directive can be found here: https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/62 (wajatimur)

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
        return $timeout(function() {
            var value;
            value = $attrs['value'];

            $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function(newValue){
                $(element).iCheck('update');
            })

            return $(element).iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-aero',
                radioClass: 'iradio_flat-aero'

            }).on('ifChanged', function(event) {
                if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        return ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.checked);
                    });
                }
                if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                    return $scope.$apply(function() {
                        return ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```